# Polymer: Bind value of Radios to Textinput

Tags: polymer

I have 3 `<input type="radio" name="radioBtn">` one for each value "none", "true" and "false". Is there a easy ways to bind the value of the selected radio Button to the value of a TextInput, without the use of onChange Events or binding them to variables in my dart script?

Something like:

```
<input type="text" value="{{radioBtn.value}}"/>
```

Comment: I don't understand why you rule out "the use of onChange Events or binding them to variables". Also, are you willing to use `<paper-radio-group>` or does this have to be implemented with standard `<input type="radio">` elements?

Comment: I don't rule them out. I just wanted to know if there is an easier way to bind the value of two html elements. Paper-Radio-group would be an option if i could use it without the paper design..